# python manage.py: No module named 'admin_tools'

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm trying to run this command on my django project:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty my_app_name
```

to create a new empty migration.

When I try to run this command in poweshell, I get this message:

```
PS C:\Travail\workout\workout-backend\workout_rest> python manage.py makemigrations --empty record
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'admin_tools'
```

The error is: `ImportError: No module named 'admin_tools'`
What am I doing wrong?

I'm on Windows 10 and I'm using VS2017 to developp my Django app.

**EDIT:**

Something very strange. When I run `pip freeze`, I get this:

```
$ pip freeze
astroid==1.4.9
colorama==0.3.7
Django==1.10.3
isort==4.2.5
lazy-object-proxy==1.2.2
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==1.6.5
six==1.10.0
wrapt==1.10.10
```

I don't know what are thoses packages. I have no mention of astroid or mccabe in my whole project. Nor in site-package folder, nor in `INSTALLED-APP`...

Comment: Probably you are missing a package `django-admin-tools` in your environment although this package is listed in Django's `INSTALLED_APPS`. Install a package via pip or remove it from `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: *Do* you have a module named admin_tools? Have you used that name anywhere? Is that what "my_app_name" actually is in your original command?

Comment: `admin-tools` is installed, I can see it on my `site-package` folder. If I run the `makemigration` command from the contextual menu on my VS solution it works well. It doesn't work only in command line.

Comment: not enough has install package, did you have it in the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes I have it in the `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: this is strange. Do you see `django-admin-tools` package in a list of installed packages then running `pip freeze` from command line?

Comment: ok there is something very strange. See my last update.

Comment: Ok I don't know how but I was kicked from my django env

Comment: Yep. If VS2017 uses virtualenv to manage environments then look for `activate.bat` or something. Got no experience with python in VS2017...